# Get window's background color

Tags: c++, mfc

Is there any function (C++, MFC) to obtain window's background color?

Comment: Do you mean the background color of any window or the windows desktop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CDC* pDc= GetDC(); 
COLORREF crBkgnd = pDc->GetBkColor();
```

Answer (score 8):

There's a default background color for windows, use GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW).  But ultimately a window decides itself what is 'background' and what is 'foreground'.  Affected by WNDCLASS.hbrBackground and the window's WM_ERASEBKGND and WM_PAINT message handlers.  Anything is possible.

Comment: +1 for `hbrBackground`. It's not necessarily set, but in that case you have to wonder if a background color even exists. (E.g. transparent windows and the like)

Comment: It can also be affected by WM_CTL_COLOR message if the default OnCtlColor behaviour is overriden.